# Will my photos and videos be gone?

Tags: factory-reset

I have a samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0, and I forgot the password. I want to save my photos and videos but I am not sure whether a factory reset will do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a custom recovery and make a backup of the entire system. The backup will be a file that's like a zip/rar/etc. Then you can get your files that way.

Take a look at http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_p3110 If you have the WIFI version of the tablet.

Take a look at http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_p3100 if you have the GSM/SIM Card version of the tablet.

As with anything, You do this at your own risk.

Comment: A factory reset will not wipe the internal storage. And why should /system be backuped if he wants to save /data/media???

Comment: Hmm I was always told factory reset would wipe everything. And I guess I should've mentioned this in the answer. But with custom recoveries  you can include the internal storage. Which would save what he wants.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab is right that why would internal storage be deleted during Factory/Hard reset? But the point applies to devices and Android having 4.4+ only IMO. For my 4.2.1 your revision 1 fits correctly.

Comment: Yeah I could of sworn at one point factory resetting a phone would have erased everything.

Comment: A factory reset wipes `/cache`, `/data` and doesn't wipe `/data/media` or `/external_sd`.

Comment: And @Firelord do you have any experience with IMEI and /efs? If so could you help me with my question?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab It wipes my Internal SD card for Android 4.2.1. But not in 4.4.2 and 5.0. // I have experience but not with Samsung. Sorry!

Comment: Maybe thats where I got confused. I figured /data included /data/media since it was a subfolder.Thanks for clearing that up.